# Overlaying canvas on a video, canvas is not reading video height and width attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So I am trying to overlay a HTML canvas element over a 500x500 video. I always want the video to be 500x500. In my code, I've set the canvas height and width to be the same as the video height and width so they overlay right on top of one another. Unfortunately, whenever I run this, the canvas element always outputs a width of 800 and a height of 600. I believe this may have something to do with the size of the original video. However, I'm really not sure why my canvas elements won't pick up on those values. I also tried directly setting my canvas height and width to 500 but when I do that it won't overlay right on top of the video. I was just wondering if anyone knew why this might be occurring and if there is anything striking out to you in my code where I am setting these elements that is causing this to occur. I have also looked at other stack overflow posts before making this one and tried to get some context from those solutions but nothing has worked for me yet.

This is my .php file:

```js
document.getElementById("bounding-tool").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.style.visibility = "visible";
    canvas.style.opacity = 0;
    //canvas.style.position = relative;
})


function create_canvas() {
    const video_frame = document.getElementById("video_frame");
    //const video = document.getElementById("video");

    const video = document.querySelector("video#video, #video video");

    //let rect = video.getBoundingClientRect();
    //console.log(rect.bottom, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right)
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (event) => {
  
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        canvas.height = 438;
        canvas.width = 584;
        
        
        const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
  
        // We're assuming that the width is the larger than the height of video.
        const shrinkFactor = canvas.height / videoHeight * 100;

        const dimensions = {
            width: Math.floor(videoWidth / 100 * shrinkFactor),
            height: Math.floor(videoHeight / 100 * shrinkFactor)
        };

        const offset = (dimensions.width - canvas.width) / 2;
        
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const loop = () => {
        context.save();
        context.fillRect(0,0,video.VideoHeight,video.videoWidth);
        context.drawImage(video,0,0,video.VideoHeight,video.videoWidth);
        
        create_bounding_tool(canvas);

        video_frame.append(canvas);
        canvas.style.visibility = "hidden";
            //canvas.style.opacity = "0";
        
        context.restore();
           context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.height,canvas.width);
        
        // bind event handler to clear button
      
        //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);*/
    }
    loop();
        
    });

}
```

```css
#video_frame{
display: inline-flex;   
position: relative;
margin-left: 7em;
width: 584px;
height: 438px;
flex: 0 0 584px;
margin-right: 0.5rem;

 margin-top: 7em;


}

#playback_frame{
    display:flex;
}

#video{
    
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/
  border: 4px solid #0033A0;
 
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px grey;*/
}


#canvas{
  
  position: absolute;
/*  margin-top: 4.4em;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title> </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Video Determiner">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Video Determiner" />
    <meta name="author" content="Video Determiner" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-seek-buttons/dist/videojs-seek-buttons.css"/>
</head>
    
        <div id="video_frame">
       <video class = "video-js vjs-big-play-centered" controls id="video" width = "584" height = "438" data-setup="{}">
      <source id ="source" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4"">
       <p class="vjs-no-js"> To view this video please enable                  JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
       <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
      </video>
    <canvas class = "video-wrapper_canvas" id = "canvas"></canvas>
            
 </div>
```

Comment: If the video is 800x600 and you show it in a 500x500 box, then you'll probably display the center of the video, having 150px drop off the left and right side, and 50px on the top and bottom. The canvas doesn't know about these margins. So to fix it you'll need to move everything 150px on the x axis and 50px on the y axis to get the correct overlay coordinates.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but how do I go about moving everything on the x and y axis for those margins? I just don't understand how to syntactically go about that for the canvas element, would that be through the use of padding? @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Are you able to make a runnable snippet? That way we can run your code and modify it to your needs.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/user3420/ncuxoq9s/11/ @EmielZuurbier I made a runnable snippet but unfortunately I'm not able to make it exactly like how it runs on my own local server since there are other components to the file that require the use of calling other js scripts as well.

Comment: Alright, that's okay. Currently the video is not expanding to the 500x500 container. Are you trying to make it to fill the container? And can you maybe tell more about how the result is supposed to be?

Comment: Yes I am trying to make it fill to the container and that's not working for me unfortunately. The result is supposed to be basically a canvas is drawn over the video based on the dimensions of the video. Then I can draw a bounding box over that area of the video and that area is captured and saved as an image. I am able to draw the bounding boxes and save the image, the only issue is the actual drawing of the canvas.

Comment: Could you give feedback on the answer?

Comment: I am actually about to try it out today which is why I haven't gotten back to you yet! But I will soon, thank you for following up. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: @EmielZuurbier So I tried it and it works somewhat the issue is the canvas draws at different locations everytime I push a button to draw it when I want it at one static location which was not happening before

Comment: It would help a lot if you could show the overlay that you're trying to make. Edit your question, click on the snippet editor ( `<>` icon) and present what you currently have as a runnable snippet.

Comment: Hi, I just did. What I am trying to do overall is draw the canvas then draw the bounding box on top of the canvas which will capture a certain area of the video and save it as an image. The issue I'm running into is the canvas is larger than the bounding box and if I try to use those classes that you suggested, I am unable to draw the actual bounding box when someone clicks on that button. The solution above works in drawing, the issue is everytime the canvas is redrawn it is redrawn in a different area. So the image that is captured is not accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a demo below which shows the video element with a canvas overlay. The canvas renders the video with the same position and size as the video itself. If you *Run code snippet* and then *Full page* you'll get the best result.

To make sure that both the video and canvas are the same size, set the container to 500x500 with the video and canvas to 100% width and height.

I've use `object-fit: cover;` to make the video fully expand the width and height of the container.

Now, the video might be a lot larger than 500x500, so we'll need to convert a (for example) 1920x1080 video to a 500x500 viewport. To do this we'll need to make some calculations.

We start off by calculating the shrink factor. The height of the video will be the same height of the canvas, but the width of the video must shrink the same amount of pixels to make sure that the aspect ratio of the video stays the same.

Therefor we calculate `height of canvas / height of video x 100`. This gives us percentage that the video must shrink to fit the height of the canvas while keeping the right aspect ratio.

Now because the width of the video is still larger than the width of the canvas, we'll need to offset the video a bit to the left to center our video. We do this by doing `(new video width - canvas width) / 2`. This is the number in pixels the video needs to move left.

Use these values to draw the video in canvas element with the right dimensions.

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.width = 500;

const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
  
  // We're assuming that the width is the larger than the height of video.
  const shrinkFactor = canvas.height / videoHeight * 100;

  const dimensions = {
    width: Math.floor(videoWidth / 100 * shrinkFactor),
    height: Math.floor(videoHeight / 100 * shrinkFactor)
  };

  const offset = (dimensions.width - canvas.width) / 2;

  const loop = () => {
    context.clearRect(
      0, 
      0, 
      canvas.width, 
      canvas.height
    );

    context.drawImage(
      video, 
      0 - offset, // Move it to the left to compensate for the width.
      0,
      dimensions.width,
      dimensions.height
    );

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  };

  loop();
});


const compare = document.getElementById('compare');
compare.addEventListener('input', event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  video.style.opacity = 1 - Number(value);
  canvas.style.opacity = value;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.video-wrapper__video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.video-wrapper__canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.slider {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.slider label {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.label-video {
  color: blue;
}

.label-canvas {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered video-wrapper__video" controls id="video" width="500" height="500" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4"/>
  </video>
  <canvas class="video-wrapper__canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <label>
    <span class="label-video">Video</span>
    <input id="compare" type="range" min="0.1" max="0.9" step="0.1" value="0.5">
    <span class="label-canvas">Canvas</span>
  </label>
</div>
```